# Navigation popUpTo not working as expected

Tags: android

I am unable to clear the splash page from the navigation backstack. In the navigation.xml file you can see that I set the `popUpTo` attribute to the splash page along with setting the `popUpToInclusive` to `true`, but this seems to have no effect.

When the app opens the splash screen is shown for one second then the main_fragment is displayed, but with a functional back arrow.

What am I missing?

[image]

activity_main.xml

```
    <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
        android:id="@+id/nav_fragment"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/toolbar"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/navigation" />
```

MainActivity.kt

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val navController = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.nav_fragment)?.findNavController()
        navController?.let {
            findViewById<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>(R.id.toolbar).setupWithNavController(navController)
        }
    }
}
```

SplashFragment.kt

```
class SplashFragment : Fragment() {
    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        GlobalScope.launch {
            withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
                delay(1000)
               
 findNavController().navigate(SplashFragmentDirections.actionSplashFragmentToMainFragment())
            }
        }
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_splash, container, false)
    }
}
```

navigation.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/navigation"
    app:startDestination="@id/splashFragment">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/splashFragment"
        android:name="org.chrisolsen.myapplication.SplashFragment"
        android:label="fragment_splash"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_splash">
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_splashFragment_to_mainFragment"
            app:destination="@id/mainFragment"
            app:popUpTo="@id/splashFragment"
            app:popUpToInclusive="true" />
    </fragment>
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/mainFragment"
        android:name="org.chrisolsen.myapplication.MainFragment"
        android:label="fragment_main"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_main" />
</navigation>
```

Comment: You should never use a splash fragment as your start destination as per the [Principles of Navigation](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-principles#fixed_start_destination).

Comment: Is it best practice to separate it into it's own Activity?

Comment: You shouldn't be using an activity or a fragment at all for a splash screen, you should be using a [launch theme](https://android.jlelse.eu/right-way-to-create-splash-screen-on-android-e7f1709ba154).

Comment: Thanks for the input. In the link you posted it is an Activity that is used with it's own theme, am I missing something?

If the original post was not a splash screen, or any other conditional screen, I would still like to know why the first fragment is not cleared from the back stack with the options set within the nav action. Do those options not work on the first item in the back stack?

Comment: I think you'll find that the system back button does *not* go back to the splash fragment (it just exits the app). Am I correct saying that it is the Up button in the action bar that you're talking about and not the system back button?

Comment: Yes, it is the Up button that I am referring to. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the expected behavior when you pop the start destination off the back stack and are using `setupWithNavController()`.

As per the [Principles of Navigation](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-principles#fixed_start_destination), you should never pop the start destination off the back stack. For a splash screen, your activity should implement a [launch theme](https://android.jlelse.eu/right-way-to-create-splash-screen-on-android-e7f1709ba154) (you should not have a separate activity or separate fragment).

Your `popUpTo` is working just fine - that's why the system back button is working correctly and causing you to exit the app directly. However, all of `NavigationUI` and the `setupWithNavController` APIs assume you **are** following the Principles of Navigation. By popping your start destination, you're triggering the same behavior as if you [deep linked into your `MainFragment`](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-deep-link#implicit):

> In this case, the Back button takes you back to the previous app, while the Up button starts your app's task on the hierarchical parent destination within your navigation graph.

But your 'previous app' is the launcher in your case.